# Array conversion in to another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, shuffle

In my project I had following kind of array.Please help me out to find solution.
Array is given below,please refer it.
It looks like FOLLOWING.

```
 [0] => Array
     (
            [Notification] => Array
               (
                  [id] => 135
                  [notification_date] => 2013-09-18
                  [short_desc] => dsfdfdfdf
                  [long_desc] =>
               )

             [NotificationProduct] => Array
                 (
                    [0] => Array
                       (
                           [id] => 41
                           [notification_id] => 135
                           [product_id] => 20
                           [Product] => Array
                                 (
                                   [id] => 20
                                   [category_id] => 2
                                   [name] => asasasa
                                  )

                      )

                     [1] => Array
                       (
                         [id] => 42
                         [notification_id] => 135
                         [product_id] => 21
                         [Product] => Array
                                 (
                                   [id] => 21
                                   [category_id] => 2
                                   [name] => corn flakcf

                                  )

                         )

                  )

    )
```

I have above kind of array.Now i want to convert it in to following way:

```
 [0] => Array
     (
            [Notification] => Array
               (
                  [id] => 135
                  [notification_date] => 2013-09-18
                  [short_desc] => dsfdfdfdf
                  [long_desc] =>
               )

             [NotificationProduct] => Array
                 (
                    [0] => Array
                       (
                           [id] => 41
                           [notification_id] => 135
                           [product_id] => 20
                           [name] => asasasa
                      )

                     [1] => Array
                       (
                         [id] => 42
                         [notification_id] => 135
                         [product_id] => 21
                         [name] => corn flakcf
                        )

                )
  )
 Is there any way to convert it into that kind of array.
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should show your approach

Comment: There is a way: you `loop` through the original array modifying it to match your intended structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following:

```
            $counter = 0;
            $responseArray = array();
            foreach($notifications as $notification){
               $responseArray[$counter]['Notification'] = $notification['Notification'];
               $counter1 = 0;
               foreach($notification['NotificationProduct'] as $notificationProduct){
                   $responseArray[$counter]['NotificationProduct'][$counter1]['product_id'] = $notificationProduct['product_id'];
                   $responseArray[$counter]['NotificationProduct'][$counter1]['product_name'] = $notificationProduct['Product']['name'];
                   $responseArray[$counter]['NotificationProduct'][$counter1]['product_desc'] = $notificationProduct['Product']['description'];
                   $counter1++;
               }
               $counter++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $name = $array[0]['NotificationProduct'][0]['product']['name']
   unset($array[0]['NotificationProduct'][0]['product'])
   $array[0]['NotificationProduct'][0]['name'] = $name;
```

Do the same for `$array[0]['NotificationProduct'][1]['product']`

Comment: does your root array has numeric index ? If so then try with `$array[0]` instead of `$array`. I have already tested the code and it is working for me.

Comment: is it possible with foreach loop?

Comment: updated the answer. yes it is possible with `foreach` loop too.

Comment: Parent array contains the numeric index

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is name `$notices`, try this:

```
foreach($notices AS $key => $val )
{
    if($key=='NotificationProduct')
    {
        foreach($val AS $idx => $np )
        {
            $notices[$key][$idx]['name'] = $notices[$key][$idx]['Product']['name'];
            unset($notices[$key][$idx]['Product']);
        }
    }
}
```